# How can I make my Chrome Extension window always on top

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

[image]

I want to make my chrome extension popup window always on top.

But I can't find how to do it.

Please let me know if you know how to do it.

Comment: I think that's not possible

Comment: did you try the css property `z-index`?

Comment: @Stefan Thank you. I didn't knew others can edit my post

Comment: @Stefan Nice top! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am looking for a solution for this problem and currently it is not possible to keep the pop up always active.

Maybe it can work to create a new window when opening the pop up, something like this.

In the file popup.html you must load this script.

```
const popupWindow = window.open(
chrome.extension.getURL("popup_window.html"),
"exampleName",
"width=300,height=300");
window.close();
```

Then you must place the contents of your popup inside the file popup_windows.html

I hope this can help you.